# How do I get custom metadata parameters ( Key- Value) for any file/container in blob storage while using Get Metadata activity in a pipeline?

Tags: azure, metadata, azure-data-factory

I am using Get Metadata activity to fetch metadata of files/folders from my azure storage account. I want to fetch the metadata parameters which are not in the field list of the Get Metadata activity for eg. custom metadata ( key- value) pair. 
Is there any way I can do this ?

Comment: I need more context to understand how are you getting the metadata. What is "Get Metadata activity"? Are you calling a storage REST API directly or not?

Comment: hi,does my answer helps you?

Comment: hi,any updates here?Any further assistance you need just let me know here.

Answer (score 0):

> Is custom metadata ( key- value) pair supported in ADF Get Metadata
>   Activity?

The answer is NO.You could only access columns mentioned in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity#metadata-options).If you have to refer more metadata information,i provide 2 workarounds with you:

1.Use Azure Function Activity to implement your custom requirements. For example,use blob storage sdk in the azure function which has [Get Properties and Metadata method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-container-properties-metadata) from blob container and files.This is for urgent.

2.Submit feedback to ADF team to ask adding more common metadata of folders and files.This is for long time.